# Insert all dates in a time period in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table having two columns (`date_ID`, `entry_Date`). I want to insert all the dates within a specific time period into the table (say dates all the dates between 2002-2030). Is there any way to do that using loops in SQL-Server?

Comment: I just want to say how cool it is that there are three 100% different ways to accomplish the same task SQL isn't really designed for, haha :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @d date='20020101' 
WHILE @d<'20300101'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Dates (entry_Date)
        VALUES (@d)
        SET @d=DATEADD(DAY,1,@d)
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

```
WITH TestItOut AS
(
    SELECT CAST('2002-01-01' as datetime) DateColumn
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateColumn + 1
    FROM TestItOut
    WHERE DateColumn + 1 <= '2030-12-31'
)

INSERT INTO YourTable (ColumnName)
SELECT DateColumn
FROM TestItOut
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

in oracle i would do

```
insert into sometable 
select to_date('01/01/2013','dd/mm/yyyy') + level 
from dual 
connect by level < 10001
```

this will generate 10000 dates from 1/1/13 with a daily interval. if you want hourly interval for example you can just change `+ level` to `+ level/24`.

this is basic ANSI sql hierarchical query - it should work in SQL server as well.

Comment: I don't think so. SQL-Server has hierarchical queries with CTEs (and Oracle, too, besides the `CONNECT BY` syntax). Like McCee's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table values(date_ID,(select entry_Date from table where entry_Date between 01/01/2002 and 01/01/2030))
```

Try this kind of query.

In place of date_ID put your appropriate value.